# Trigger store action from outside vue app

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to include buttons in various places on a page, outside the Vue components elsewhere on the page, that trigger store actions through a click event. I have buttons within my components that do as much, connecting to methods after `v-on:click` that then trigger store actions through `this.$store.dispatch`. Is it possible to do this from outside of Vue?

Comment: This is a very broad question and lacks detail. Have you tried anything? Are you having any particular problems?

Comment: Theoretically, if your `Vuex.Store` instance can be made available within the global scope, you can directly call `dispatch()` on it but we don't even know how your app is built so it's all just guessing.

Comment: How would I make the store available? I read about importing it, but my other basic script that would handle click events is not written as a module.

Comment: I know it's very broad, and I've been frustrated because I've searched for weeks on how to do something like this and haven't found anything promising. I'm building a small app that integrates with a WordPress site to provide some frontend functionality and integration with a backend CRM plugin, so I'm not writing one monolithic SPA.

Comment: You can add a reference to `window`, as is done to aid testing in this article [Testing Vue web applications with Vuex data store](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/28/testing-vue-web-application-with-vuex-data-store-and-rest-backend/#store-testing).

Comment: Have you tried anything? If the button elements are already on the page, you could even add event handlers to them (via `addEventListener()`) within your `Vue` app's `mounted` hook and still use `this.$store.dispatch()`

Comment: You're already using Vue, why not use Vue? It's going to be hard to come up with alternatives when you haven't explained what's wrong with Vue for your use case. As far as I know, you can make buttons and add click handlers, in Vue. That's all that you've told us you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, you can do what you want by hanging your Vue instance directly off of the `window`, for instance:

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

```
window.IVue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  store: new Vuex.Store({
    actions: {
      hello() {
        return Promise.resolve('Hello from the store!')
      }
    }
  })
})

window.IVue.$store.dispatch('hello').then((message) => {
  Vue.set(window.IVue, 'message', message)
})
```

[And here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5ze1f9s/)

You'll see the message is **Hello from the store!**